# Errors in Averaging Function Script Code?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, vim, awk

I wrote a (questionable) piece of code for a user-defined average function, where the code takes the second argument of the command line invocation, and uses its respective field in an input file and finds the average of all of those fields (in a single column).

The input file is named `players.data`:

```
LBJ:1:1:1:1
KBB:2:2:2:2
KDD:3:3:3:3
PPP:4:4:4:4
LLO:5:5:5:5
```

My function is supposed to, depending on the second argument at invocation, find the average of the 5 numbers in either the 3rd, 4th or fifth column (field).

So given invocation `nawk -f testscript2.script players.data Row3` should use Row3 as `ARGV[2]`, and thus according to the below if statement sum row 3 in `players.data` and thus output `The average of row Row3 is 5.00`

Error-ridden code listed below:

```
BEGIN{FS = ":"}
{
function average(ARGV[2]){

    if(ARGV[2] == "Row3"){
            sumJan += $3
            avgJan = sumJan / 5
            printf "The average of row %-10s is %6.2f", ARGV[2], avgJan
            }
    else if(ARGV[2] == "Row4"){
            sumFeb += $4;
            avgFeb = sumFeb / 5
            printf "The average of row %-10s is %6.2f", ARGV[2], avgFeb
            }
    else if(ARGV[2] == "Row5"){
            sumMar += $5
            avgMar = sumMar / 5
            printf "The average of row %-10s is %6.2f", ARGV[2], avgMar
            }
    else{
            print "Error: Invalid Input"
            }
    }
}
{average(ARGV[2])
}
```

Here is the summary of the current errors:

```
nawk: a6c.script: line 8: syntax error at or near function
nawk: a6c.script: line 15: syntax error at or near else
nawk: a6c.script: line 20: syntax error at or near else 
nawk: a6c.script: line 25: syntax error at or near else
nawk: a6c.script: line 28: syntax error at or near }
```

How could this code be fixed such that when the above invocation is passed the desired output is displayed?

Comment: Looks like a homework question to me.

Comment: Damn right it is. But I've tried my ass off, and would appreciate if one of you could help.

Answer (score 3):

### First, grammar errors

You have one extra `{` before the line with `function`:

```
BEGIN{FS = ":"}
{
function average(ARGV[2]){
   ...
}
```

So it should be:

```
BEGIN{FS = ":"}
function average(ARGV[2]){
   ...
}
```

Then, you are creating a function that receives a parameter. This parameter is just supposed to have the local scope of the function, hence calling it `ARGV[2]` is just a big misunderstanding of scopes. Just use something like:

```
function average(row) {

    # things with the variable row

}
```

And you use `ARGV[2]` when *calling* the function: `average(ARGV[2])`.

### Then, concept errors

You are using a function that you call on every iteration to calculate the average. If you want to use functions, use one to keep track of the values and finally, and just then, print the values.

Also, you are repeating a bunch of code in all your `if - else if - else` conditions. Note that as much as you can say `$4`, you can also say `var=row` and then use `$var` to use the `row`<sup>th</sup>'s value:

```
if(ARGV[2] == "Row3"){
            sumJan += $3
            avgJan = sumJan / 5
            printf "The average of row %-10s is %6.2f", ARGV[2], avgJan
            }
```

can be a generic:

```
sum += $row
avg = sum / 5
printf "The average of row %-10s is %6.2f", row, avgJan
```

### Altogether, this can be a succinct one-liner

```
$ awk -F: -v col=4 '{sum+=$col} END {print sum/NR}' file
3
```

This keeps a sum of the column number `col` and finally divides by the number of lines.